# Sorting keys from and object based on the difference in value Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let scores = {
  A: 30,
  B: 40,
  C: 35,
  D: 90
}



function getScores(students) {

  let result = []
  let keys = Object.keys(scores)
  let difference = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    console.log('key', keys[i])
    if (scores[keys[i]] < scores[keys[i + 1]]) {
      difference = scores[keys[i + 1]] - scores[keys[i]]
      if (difference <= 15) {
        result.push(keys[i])
        result.push(keys[i + 1])
        console.log('result', result)
      }
      console.log('>>>', difference)
    } else {
      difference = scores[keys[i]] - scores[keys[i + 1]]
      if (difference <= 15) {
        if (!result.includes(keys[i])) {
          result.push(keys[i])
        }
        result.push(keys[i + 1])
        console.log('result', result)
      }

    }
    if (!result.includes(keys[i])) {
      result.push([keys[i]])
    }
    console.log('<<<', difference)
  }

}

getScores(scores)
```

I'm trying to group these into an array based on a condition that the value is less than `15`.  If a key and the next key have a difference less than `15` then they should be pushed to the results array.  This works some what in the code I have.  When run I get `result = ['A', 'B', 'C']`  What I'm trying to get is `result = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D']]` so `A` `B` and `C` are `15` or less so they are in one nested array and `D` is in a separate array.  I realize this is probably less than optimized code.  Looking for any suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: Is the result always just 2 entries - a list of those entries who are within 15 of one of their neighbors and another where the entry is more than 15 from either neighbor?  Maybe you can show what you'd expect from scores like this `let scores = { A: 30, B: 40, C: 35, D: 90, E:80, F:10, G:11 };`?

Comment: Ideally I would want to sort them before hand and then loop over them to put them in groups so that the difference between the scores in the group is never greater than 15. so D and E would be in a group.  then A,B, and C would be in a group.  then F and G in a group.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `reduce`.

You can store the object keys in a variable, then reduce over the array. In the reducer function, check whether the value of the property after the current has a score difference of less than 16, and if so, push the current item to the last array in the accumulator array. Otherwise, push a new array with only the current item.

```js
let scores = {A: 30, B: 40, C: 35, D: 90};

const keys = Object.keys(scores)
const result = keys.reduce((a, b, i) => {
  if (scores[b] - scores[keys[i + 1]] <= 15 && a[a.length - 1]) {
    a[a.length - 1].push(b)
  } else {
    a.push([b])
  }
  return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I had to modify it some to meet the requirements.  There's probably a little bit simpler way.  I'll keep playing with it put here's what I got.

Answer (score 0):

You should also take care of negative values so use `Math.abs`.

```js
let scores = { A: 30, B: 40, C: 35, D: 90 };

const result = [];

Object.entries(scores).reduce(
  ([previousKey, previousValue], [key, value]) => {
    if (result.length === 0)
      result.push([previousKey]);
    if (Math.abs(previousValue - value) <= 15)
      result[result.length - 1].push(key);
    else
      result.push([key]);
    return [key, value];
  }
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let scores = {
  A: 10,
  B: 40,
  C: 90,
  D: 80,
  E: 20,
  F: 10,
  G: 100,
  H: 95
}

let sorted = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(scores).sort(([,a],[,b]) => b-a)
  )
let finalResult = []

function groups(students){
const keys = Object.keys(sorted)
const result = keys.reduce((a, b, i) => {
   
  if (sorted[b] - sorted[keys[i+1]] <= 15 && !a.includes(b)) {
    a.push(b)
    a.push(keys[i+1])
  }  
 if(sorted[b] - sorted[keys[i+1]] > 15){
   if(!a.includes(b))a.push(b)
   if(!finalResult.includes(a))finalResult.push(a)
    a = []
      
  }
 if(!finalResult.includes(a))finalResult.push(a)
 return a
}, [])
  console.log(finalResult)
}
```

This can probably be simplified in some way but it did get the job done.